# Can I add fix-it for my own deprecations in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, deprecated

Trying to find if I can create my own "fix it" suggestion for my own deprecations? Is it possible at all? If yes, then any resource would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `deprecated` attribute:

```
@interface MyObject: NSObject
- (void)oldMethod
    __attribute__((deprecated("Don't use this", "newMethod")))
    ;
- (void)newMethod;
@end
```

If you want to deprecate as of a specific OS version, you can use [clang's `availability` attribute](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AttributeReference.html#availability). Note that you can only deprecate based on OS version, not on your own library's version.

Example:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MyObject: NSObject
- (void)oldMethod
    __attribute__((availability(ios,deprecated=12.0,replacement="newMethod")))
    ;
- (void)newMethod;
@end

@implementation MyObject

- (void)oldMethod { }
- (void)newMethod { }

@end

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        MyObject *o = [[MyObject alloc] init];
        [o oldMethod]; // Xcode offers a fix-it to use newMethod instead.
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You can use the `API_DEPRECATED_WITH_REPLACEMENT` macro defined in `<os/availability.h>` instead of directly using the clang attribute, if you want. There are comments in that header file explaining its use.